# How do i implement facebook chat in xamarin (cross-platform)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

I am creating an app that allows users to communicate with doctors in real time via a chat system. I was wondering if there are any sample codes out there that shows how can one implement facebook/whatsapp chat system into a xamarin cross platform project. If possible any other chat app sample links are also appreciated.

Comment: do you want to include SOMETHING LIKE facebook/whatsapp or do you want to include either of those specific platforms? if it's the latter: it's not possible (at least not through public APIs)

Comment: If the latter is not possible i can work on creating a custom one. I know there are examples available using Azure Mobile App as a server, however, my business doesn't allow for such tools. I might have to create a server and host the app there. So if you have any such code examples or even some insight about that, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the Azure .NET Web stack can be hosted 'on premise' (on your company servers) too, so those examples you've already seen might just work.

In general you'll need a real time communication framework. There is a decent overview [over there](https://deepstream.io/blog/realtime-framework-overview/).

It's all depending on your requirements and the time and effort you want to put into it.